# Acceleration in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, acceleration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I have a robot model that I spawn in Gazebo, and I have developed a client, which indicates its position and velocities. Is there any way to indicate its acceleration, is there any service to call in order to declare it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37938/acceleration-in-gazebo/) by [Penny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1547/penny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest asking this on answers.gazebosim.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1